# Failed to filter and delete old indices of elasticsearch using curator python API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I'm trying to use curator python API to periodically delete old logs in elasticsearch.
In my code output, it seems I can't filter the indices I want which stuck me several days.
Anyone can help to have a look if I have done anything wrong?
I used elasticsearch-curator version 5.4.1 and tested elasticsearch 5.5 on EC2, aws elasticsearch 5.5 and aws elasticsearch 6.0 and the results are the same.

Following is my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import elasticsearch
import curator

def handler():
  client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(['http://XX.153.17.133:9200'])
  ilo = curator.IndexList(client)
  print ilo.all_indices
  print ilo.filter_by_regex(kind='prefix', value='mov')
  print ilo.filter_by_age(source='creation_date', direction='older', unit='seconds', unit_count=2)
  #delete_indices = curator.DeleteIndices(ilo)
  #delete_indices.do_action()
  return

handler()
```

And following is the output:

```
/Users/junyu/PycharmProjects/es-curator/bin/python 
/Users/junyu/PycharmProjects/es-curator/es-curator.py
[u'movie']
None
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which indices do you expect to see? Perhaps I can help out.

First, you will only see output from your `print ilo.filter*` lines if you have logging set up.

If you want to see what indices remain after the filters, then try `print ilo.indices` (that's the working list).

Comment: Great. I'm a new guy of curator python API. It works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will only see output from your `print ilo.filter*` lines if you have logging set up.

If you want to see what indices remain after the filters, then try [`print ilo.indices`](http://curator.readthedocs.io/en/v5.4.1/objectclasses.html#curator.indexlist.IndexList.indices), as that is the working list.